# Buttons to load different Datasources to a Panel on a different Page

Tags: google-app-maker

Seems simple enough, but...

I have a Page (a dashboard) with buttons, one button for each Program. I have a different page with Tasks in a Table. 
I want to load the Tasks page with the tasks for that Program from that programs button on the dashboard Page.
I've attempted multiple angles using Relations, queries and scripts from multiple tutorials and templates I get all the parts working but not working together.

This is how I think it should work.
On the dashboard Page each button calls its own script like:

```
currentProgram = "ALL";

function btnProgram1_click() {
  currentProgram = "Program1";
  app.showPage(app.pages.Tasks);
}
```

Then on the Tasks Page > Panel > Event > onAttach calls:

```
function loadTasks(){
  if(currentProgram == "Program1"){
    app.datasources.qryProgram1Tasks.load();
  }

  if(currentProgram == "Program2"){
    app.datasources.qryProgram2Tasks.load();
  }
}
```

I have SQL Datasources on the Tasks model like `qryProgram1Tasks` with a query expression for `"Program1"` and they return data as expected.

Seems to me this is what is not working as wanted to load, or replace and refresh a designated datasource to the panel `app.datasources.qryProgram1Tasks.load();`

Comment: So the way this looks to me is that you are declaring a function on your button onclick event and you are also declaring a function for you Tasks page onattach event. Meaning, you are not actually calling your functions. I am also not seeing where the variable currentProgram is declared so from the code you are showing, currentProgram may in fact be undefined. I think you may have an easier time just unloading both program datasources and loading the respective datasource for your program buttons.

Comment: Thanks Markus, you have revived my hope that there is a viable community here. I did change the approach and will soon update my post and check in on your other posts here as I expect there to learn some things.